# How to structure various microservices components in AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, microservices

I have a new web application which in our company we have decided to be like below and i am creating the architecture for the first time so would require some inputs.

1) Front End - React.js

2) Backend - Java (Spring boot)

3) Architecture - Microservices

4) Infra - AWS

5) CI - Jenkins

We have divided the development in three phases

**Phase 1 -** Create AWS infra, front end service and few backend services using Spring Boot and Spring Cloud. Keep the use of AWS services to as minimum as possible

**Phase 2 -** Create more backend services and dockerize everything

**Phase 3 -** Orchestrate previous phase using Kubernetes and use more AWS services if required

I am at phase 1 and after going through lot of resources and study material, need help in creating production grade architecture and AWS environment. There are lot of individual resources but did not find much on how the real system should look like in when it is live.

**my understanding -** have a micro frontend and microservices in backend. Client will request webpage in browser the request will come to UI service.

- I am confused what is the order of components.
- Either it should come to react app first and then it would go to api
  gateway or ELB?
- Do we need ELB?
- Request would come to ELB and then it will go to API gateway and
  further?
- Request would come to ELB and then it will go to API gateway and
  further?

Option A or B? Or if both are wrong? Or where should be arrows
   heading from client to backend services?

**Option A**
[image]

**Option B**
[image]

Detailed information what I am trying to achieve is mentioned in question: [Production Grade microservices architecture in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59400935/production-grade-microservices-architecture-in-aws)

I am not sure if there are any resources available on web which i can refer which explains it. if anyone has i would be happy to go through them.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse some examples and explanations from web to make your diagram organize and your application to be efficient. Here is a link might help [Microservice Architecture](https://www.devteam.space/blog/microservice-architecture-examples-and-diagram/) and here [AWS Sample Diagrams](https://medium.com/@warren2lynch/aws-architecture-diagram-with-2019-new-icons-over-50-examples-d401a76c6d5c)